# Where can I get a VB.net - WPF - Trending Graph Control

Tags: .net, graph, controls, trending

We're trying to show 4 trend graphs and will be adding data to them them at a rate of about 1 point every second.  In the end each trend needs to show around 600 points.

Currently we are using the graphing tools from Syncfusion but they are unable to redraw the graphs at the speed we require.  I believe the issue is due to the fact that we're using a 'graphing' tool not a 'trending' tool, so its redrawing the entire line every refresh.

The application is running on a beast of a box:
Dell 2950 with:
dual processors(Intel Xeon's) with quad cores,
2.99GHZ, and 8gig's of ram.

Do you know where we can get a high speed trending control?  WPF controls preferred.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.

Comment: @honk - Just like your comment on a 6 year old question.

Comment: No offense intended. I know that your answer was on-topic six years ago. I left the comment after reviewing a late answer on your question. That answer got deleted because it was an answer on a question that is off-topic now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look no further, use [visifire](http://visifire.com/silverlight_chart_designer.php).

Comment: We ended up implementing ChartFX's WPF trend control.  At the time Visifire's trend seemed so-so.  However now it looks better and is WAY cheaper in a corporate setting.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Graphit](https://graphit.codeplex.com/).
We use it and it's still smooth with 10 curves, each curve around 5000 data points.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how well it will fit your needs, but you might take a look at http://www.visifire.com/
Visifire is an open source graphing control for Silverlight and WPF.

Comment: Trending is a different task to graphing.  Graphing is non real time display of data in a graphical format.  Trending is real time display of data against time.  In addition Trending tools allow zoom of data and timespan ranges

Comment: As you can see from the example in the top right corner on http://www.visifire.com/silverlight_charts_gallery.php , Visifire now features real-time updating.

Comment: @Totty .. I saw their claim of "Now with real time updates", but when I  went through their demo video of chart types I saw nothing that showed that functionality or anything that indicated their product wasn't just data graphing.  So I would be skeptical of using it as a Trending tool

Comment: (continued) I have also gone through their 2.x documentation and nothing jumps out as it being a Trending tool